# Problem with dynamic-memory-allocation while using constructors to a class

Tags: c++, oop, dynamic-memory-allocation

i am learning the concept of object oriented programing

Started with dynamic memory allocation , and find a problem in this code .
I cant find the problem in this code , in my opinion it all good

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Team
{
    private:
    char *name;
    char stadium[20];
    char city[20];
    public:
    Team(const char *i=" ",const char *stadium=" ",const char *city=" ")
    {
        name=new char [strlen(i)];
        strcpy(name,i);
        strcpy(this->stadium,stadium);
        strcpy(this->city,city);
    }
  const char *getName() {
  return name;
  }
  const char *getCity() {
  return city;
  }
  const char *getStadium() {
  return stadium;
  }
  void setName(char *name) {
  strcpy(this->name, name);
  }
  ~Team() {
      delite [] name;
  }
};

};
int main()
{
  Team *e1 = new Team("Real Madrid", "Madrid", "Santiago Bernabeu");
  Team *e2 = new Team(*e1);
  cout << e1->getName();
  cout << "-";
  cout << e2->getName();
  e1->setName("Barselona");
  cout << e1->getName();
  cout << "-";
  cout << e2->getName();
  delete e1;
  delete e2;
   
   return 0;
}
```

I was looking to fix this problem more then 3 hours ... and didn't find anything , i know this may not be the way i need to search for solution . But i get tired of trying to fix this .

Some of the errors i get

```cpp
main.cpp: In constructor ‘Team::Team(const char*, const char*, const char*)’:
main.cpp:13:24: error: ‘strlen’ was not declared in this scope
         name=new char [strlen(*i)];
                        ^~~~~~
main.cpp:13:24: note: suggested alternative: ‘mbrlen’
         name=new char [strlen(*i)];
                        ^~~~~~
                        mbrlen
main.cpp:14:9: error: ‘strcpy’ was not declared in this scope
         strcpy(name,i);
         ^~~~~~
main.cpp:14:9: note: suggested alternative: ‘strtoq’
         strcpy(name,i);
         ^~~~~~
         strtoq
```

I tried this code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class Team {
private:
  char *name;
  char city[20];
  char stadion[30];
public:
  Team(char *name = "", char *city = "", char *stadion = "") {
  this->name = new char[20];
  strcpy(this->name, name);
  strcpy(this->city, city);
  strcpy(this->stadion, stadion);
  }
  Team(const Team &e) {
  strcpy(name, e.name);
  strcpy(city, e.city);
  strcpy(stadion, e.stadion);
  }
  const char *getName() {
  return name;
  }
  const char *getCity() {
  return city;
  }
  const char *getStadion() {
  return stadion;
  }
  void setName(char *name) {
  strcpy(this->name, name);
  }
  ~Team() {
     // delite [] name;
  }
};
int main() {
  Team *e1 = new Team("Real Madrid", "Madrid", "Santiago Bernabeu");
  Team *e2 = new Team(*e1);
  cout << e1->getName();
  cout << "-";
  cout << e2->getName();
  e1->setName("Barselona");
  cout << e1->getName();
  cout << "-";
  cout << e2->getName();
  delete e1;
  delete e2;
  return 0;
}
```

And get this error

```
main.cpp:44:26: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]                                                   
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Could you add the error message and some info about what have you tried?

Comment: i will edit post now , no worries :)

Comment: What's wrong with `std::string`? And if you insist on manually allocating memory for strings, be aware that `strlen(i)` (not `strlen(*i)`) does not include the null-terminator. Also `delite [] name;` is not valid C++

Comment: fixed that but still not working , can the problem be that i am creating a object in dynamic memory with dynamic allocated parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected some typos in your code, modified copy constructor of `class Team`, and it works fine on my PC.

```
class Team
{
private:
    char* name;
    char stadium[20];
    char city[20];
public:
    Team(const char* i = " ", const char* stadium = " ", const char* city = " ")
    {
        name = new char[strlen(i) + 1];  // +1 for null-terminate
        strcpy(name, i);
        strcpy(this->stadium, stadium);
        strcpy(this->city, city);
    }
    // allocating memory for Team::name needed, but I delegated it to above constructor.
    Team(const Team& e) :Team(e.name, e.stadium, e.city) {
        // empty
    }
    const char* getName() {
        return name;
    }
    const char* getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    const char* getStadium() {
        return stadium;
    }
    void setName(const char* name) {  // must be const char*. Not char*!!
        strcpy(this->name, name);
    }
    ~Team() noexcept {
        if(name)        
            delete[] name;   // delete[] name, NOT delite
    }
};
```

Here is more preferred way of writing C++ classes.
As some comments already told, prefer using `std::string` to `char*`. I know it maybe hard to get used to a C++ classes but, trust me, `std::string` is far better than `char*`. With `std::string`, you don't need to allocate memory yourself, and you're not required to write additional copy constructor and destructor.

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

class Team
{
public:
    Team(void) = default;
    explicit Team(const string& name, const string& stadium, const string& city)
        :name_(name), stadium_(stadium), city_(city) {}

    void setName(const string& new_name) { name_ = new_name; }
    string getName(void) const { return name_; }
    string getCity(void) const { return city_; }
    string getStadium(void) const { return stadium_; }
private:
    string name_;
    string stadium_;
    string city_;
};
```

Comment: i tried this but still not working ... 
`code
error: ‘strlen’ was not declared in this scope
         name = new char[strlen(i) + 1];  // +1 for null-terminate
main.cpp:15:9: error: ‘strcpy’ was not declared in this scope
         strcpy(name, i);
`

Comment: @World You should include `<cstring>` in C++ to use `strcpy()` and `strlen()`.

Comment: yea .. that was the problem so ... Never mind ty a lot big brain boy :D <3

Comment: Pedantic point - when copying strings to character buffers, should really use `strncpy` or `strcpy_s`. (stadium and city).  Also if you have naked pointers there needs to be a default constructor to initialise it to `nullptr`, or declare it `deleted`.

Comment: I'd also suggest perhaps using rvalue refs for the constructor, so you can create an instance with `char-const*` strings.

Answer (score 0):

Add `#include <cstring>` in your main file:
C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<cstring>  // Add this in your code
```

In your main file:

```
int main() {
   ...
}
```